# Django makemigrations throws error because unknown field

Tags: python, django, wagtail

I am working on my first wagtail app. I already got some issues with the migrations. I wanted to chagne the `models.ImageField` to `ImageChooserBlock()` after I already did the first migration. This is my new model:

```
class AboutPage(Page):

    template= "event/about.html"
    
    text = RichTextField()
    team_photo = ImageChooserBlock()

    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        FieldPanel('team_photo'),
        FieldPanel('text'),
    ]
```

But this throws the following error in the console:

```
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Unknown field(s) (group_foto) specified for AboutConnectedPage
```

After running `makemigrations`. What could be the problem?

Comment: Could you share the full traceback ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is not valid - `ImageChooserBlock` cannot be used outside of StreamField. Perhaps you want [a foreign key to Wagtail's Image model](https://docs.wagtail.org/en/stable/getting_started/tutorial.html#images) instead?

```
team_photo = models.ForeignKey(
    'wagtailimages.Image', blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name='+'
)
```